# Query on Container-Pluggable database

Tags: oracle-12c

My Container database (CDBROOT) is showing as read-write mode and while my pluggable database is showing as mount-state. Does that mean the application is using the container database and not the pluggable? Also, is it possible to move back to the non-container database architecture?

Comment: You have to create a new database if you want to go back to non-container architecture. Datapump probably the best way to transfer your database between the two.

Answer (score 2):

If your pluggable database is not open, then you will not be able to connect to it in regular fashion. You need to check the connection descriptor that you application uses in order to check where it connects.

When you create a PDB, it is automatically added in the listener as a service. You can check using

```
lsnrctl status
```

To connect to a specific pluggable database, you need to use its service name.
You can start a pluggable database by connecting to the container and issuing:

```
alter pluggable database <PDB_NAME> open;
```

To switch your context to a specific pluggable database when connected to the container, use:

```
alter session set container = <PDB_NAME>;
```

After that all commands will be ran against that pluggable database.

**References:**

[Introduction to the Multitenant Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234)

[Connecting to Container Databases (CDB) and Pluggable Databases (PDB)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1)